# I get "Type mismatch" error when I use a function as parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope use the function AA as the parameter of the function BB in the following code, but I get the two errors.

Error 1: I hope to assign the result of function cc to dd, but I failed.

Error 2: I hope to invoke the function BB, but the parameter AA(3) is incorrect.

How can I fix the errors? Thanks!

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        BB(1,AA(3)); //Error 2
    }



    fun AA(aa:Int): Int{
       return aa+10
    }

    fun BB(bb:Int, cc:(Int) -> Int){
        val dd:Int=cc(Int); //Error 1
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bb+dd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Kotlin syntax is wrong.

How you have it written, the BB method would be:

`fun BB(bb: Int, cc: Int) {`

What you’re passing BB is the **RESULT** of the AA function (aka: an `Int`).

In other words, why are you receiving a function (AA) inside (BB) if you are already invoking the function when you’re calling “BB”. Since `AA` takes an Int and returns an Int, the signature for the BB function expects just two ints. The Call to `AA(Int)` happened on your `ERROR 2` line.

It’s not clear what you’re trying to do (given the code of your Toast), but you can use TypeAlias & Bound references like this:

```
typealias SomeType = (Int) -> Int

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val a = this::AA // Save a Bound Reference to the function.

        BB(1, a) // Call BB and pass a value and a function
    }

    fun AA(aa: Int): Int {
        return aa + 10
    }

    fun BB(bb: Int, cc: SomeType) {
        val dd = cc(bb) // call `cc` which is really `AA(Int) -> Int`
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
fun AA(aa: Int): Int {
        return aa + 10
    }

    fun BB(bb: Int, cc: Int) {
        val dd: Int = cc
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bb + dd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```